# Color of outline on input field

Tags: html, css, input

So I have `input type="number"` elements and when you click in the field, there is a blue glow/border appearing Is it possible to change this to another color?

I am aware I can change the background or arrows and such, but I am unsure if I can change the default blue color when you click in the field.

```html
<div class="b">
    <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100" size="38"> 
</div>
```

Comment: I was very surprised not to find a previous version of this question. This is a nice clean one in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's controlled by the various [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) styles. For instance, to make it green, you can use `outline-color: green`. You can apply this to all `input` elements (using the `:focus` pseudo-class), or to just the `type="number"` ones if you like. Note that for it to work in Firefox, you have to supply `outline-style` (it's optional for other browsers). Here's an example:

```css
input[type=number]:focus {
    outline-color: green;
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
    <input class="number" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="-1" max="100" size="38">
</div>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but my firefox outline is still blue.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov - For Firefox, it needs `outline-style` (and so you have to add the `:focus` pseudo-class unless you want it to always have the outline).

Answer (score 3):

it works in ff:

```
input:focus {
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #f00;
}
```